# Разница между typing.Any и ellipsis

Tags: python, pycharm, аннотации

В чём разница между `typing.Any` и `...`? Эквивалентны ли они в данном случае?

```
import typing


def foo(x: ...):
    pass


def bar(x: typing.Any):
    pass


foo(42) # No warning in PyCharm
bar(42) # No warning in PyCharm
```

Comment: Нет, mypy кидает ошибку в функции foo

Comment: @andreymal а с точки зрения языка Python? Внешняя софтина может что угодно написать

Comment: Языку вообще плевать, он никак не обрабатывает аннотации, они нужны только внешним софтинам (и некоторым странным библиотекам вроде pydantic)

Comment: @andreymal тогда вопрос вдогонку https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1251661/432671

Comment: А вот в случае с PyCharm как-то даже не совсем понятно, почему он ошибку не кидает. Учитывая, что аннотации могут использоваться не только для type hints — вероятно, он просто пытается игнорировать некорректные аннотации. Например, `def foo(x: 1/0):` тоже не выдаёт никаких ошибок, хотя такой код даже не запустится