# Передача partial в Callable аргумент выдает предупреждение

Tags: python, pycharm, аннотации, mypy

Почему PyCharm выдаёт предупреждение о несоответствии типов на такой код?

```
import collections.abc
import functools


def bar(op: collections.abc.Callable[[int, int], int], x: int, y: int) -> int:
    return op(x, y)


def foo(callable_object: collections.abc.Callable[[int, int], int]) -> int:
    return callable_object(2, 2)


print(foo(functools.partial(bar, lambda x, y: x + y)))
```

Почему Mypy не выдаёт предупреждения на такой код (лишний параметр у лямбды)?

```
import collections.abc
import functools


def bar(op: collections.abc.Callable[[int, int], int], x: int, y: int) -> int:
    return op(x, y)


def foo(callable_object: collections.abc.Callable[[int, int], int]) -> int:
    return callable_object(2, 2)


print(foo(functools.partial(bar, lambda x, y, z: x + y)))
```

Comment: Похоже на баги во внешних софтинах https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/1484; https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-35363

Comment: А какая версия mypy?

Comment: А впрочем неважно, в текущей версии partial определён как [тупой класс с Any-аргументами](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/master/stdlib/functools.pyi#L67), так что не судьба :(

Comment: Его [пытались накостылить получше](https://github.com/python/typeshed/pull/2878), но потом [передумали](https://github.com/python/typeshed/pull/3077)